# Login to Sharepoint site from Windows Form Application (Web Services)

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm part of a Company, this company has a SharePoint site for employees to use.

When you first visit the site, it requires a Windows Basic Authentication asking for username and password. After credentials are entered it takes you to the main SharePoint site. 
[image]

**I don't have direct access to the sites Database, meaning I can't use client object model.**

When the SharePoint site is accessed I want it to navigate to a specific part of the site (The Tasks/Issues).

This SharePoint site has a tab for Tasks and Issues, the user/employee needs to visit this part of the site to enter a new Task with an Issue. The image below is a screenshot of the Windows Form Application. 
[image]

If you need more information just ask, sorry if everything seems unclear.

Comment: Side note: there is no such thing as "Windows Basic Authentication" - there are "Windows Authentincation" (NTML/Kerberos generally handled without any password prompts), "Basic authentication" (sending plain text password per HTTP specification), "Forms authentication" (where one signs in on custom page and it than sets necessary information on requests via cookies). Please clarify which one you are talking about.

Comment: Not exactly sure, it's a Windows Security.
http://i57.tinypic.com/a2epoy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do this using Web Services you'll need to use the following,

```
WService.Lists list = new WService.Lists();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        list.Credentials = cred;
```

Sometimes you wouldn't have a Web Service reference, in that case you'll need,

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(new Uri("http://website"), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));
        client.Credentials = cc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll use the `ClientContext` to access the site.  You'll authenticate using the `Credentials` Property:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteURL))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    //TODO do stuff with context to query site data
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that in most cases with SharePoint and Windows Auth you just need [CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The fact that they need to enter the credentials when accessing the site through the browser would indicate that that probably isn't an option.  If it is, then you don't even need to do that, just don't set the `Credentials` property at all and it will use the default credentials by default.

Comment: @Prosperity Google is full of tutorials on how to use the client object model.  Just do some searching and you'll find plenty to choose from.

Comment: @Servy I'm assuming that you'd need Admin Rights to the SharePoint site to be able to do this?

Comment: @Prosperity Nope.  You'll be able to do whatever the user could do if they were accessing the site through the web UI.  If they can query a given list, then they can query that list.  If a you try to change a site setting that the user doesn't have permissions to change, you'll get an exception at runtime.  A site admin will of course be able to do a lot more than a non-admin user.

Comment: @Servy This is exactly what I want, but I'm having a hard time grasping how I should approach this. Do you have an example on how I could login into a SharePoint site (Having to enter credentials).

Comment: @Prosperity This is exactly the code that you would use to create a connection to the site, given a particular set of credentials.  This is all you need to have.  If you want to know how to figure out what username/password to use, that's a winforms question and really mostly dependent on what UI you want to have, more so than any actual difficulty in implementing it.  Sounds like you simply need to spend some time looking through some basic Winform and SharePoint client object model tutorials.  I certainly can't write an entire application for you.

Comment: @Servy I'll look into Winform and SharePoint Object Model, thank you for your help. Oh just one more thing, is the YouTube tutorial that Greg provided useful to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Prosperity Couldn't tell you.  I haven't watched it.

Answer (score 0):

Servy wants you to use the SharePoint Client Object Model

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

class DisplayWebTitle
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://intranet.contoso.com");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(site);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", site.Title);
    }
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee857094%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK4oZqyllik

Comment: Servy even posted an answer 26 minutes before you posted this one to indicate this... (while also properly disposing of the client context and indicating how to supply credentials, as the question asks).

Comment: I just posted this for others to help put everything in context